# Django group by foreign key and return its object

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-orm

I need some help with django orm.
I have an EvaluationScore model and a Category Model

```
class EvaluationScore(models.Model):
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4)
    score = models.FloatField(null=True)
    category = models.ForeignKey('Category', on_delete=models.CASCADE, db_column='id_category')

class Category(models.Model):
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
```

What I want to do is to query EvaluationScore and return the average by category. So I did something like this

```
EvaluationScore.objects.values('category').annotate(Avg('score'))
```

The problem is that it returns a dict like this for every gategory

```
{'category': UUID('67a56798-24da-4800-af15-79b9839a3f84'), 'score__avg': 28.166666666666668}
```

What I need is the category object, not only the UUID. Is there a way to do so?

Comment: Why not perform the query on the Category model?

Answer (score 1):

```
Category.objects.annotate(Avg('evaluationscore__score'))
```